# Automating the file name in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to see if i can combine multiple tables into 1. I'm halfway there but not quite there, and I prefer not to do it manually. I'm using bigquery, and they have the noaa.gsod dataset from year 1929 to 2022. i'm looking to combine the temperature data from each month from the different locations into a single dataset. So far, I've managed to find out how to combine 3 or ore datasets into a single table:

```sql
WITH avgtemptable1 AS (
    SELECT stn, year, mo, ROUND(AVG(temp)) AS avg_temp
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod1955`
    GROUP BY stn, year, mo 
), avgtemptable2 AS (
    SELECT stn, year, mo, ROUND(AVG(temp)) AS avg_temp
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod1956`
    GROUP BY stn, year, mo 
), avgtemptable3 AS (
    SELECT stn, year, mo, ROUND(AVG(temp)) AS avg_temp
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod1957`
    GROUP BY stn, year, mo 
)
SELECT *
FROM avgtemptable1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM avgtemptable2
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM avgtemptable3
```

From this it's apparent that doing this for almost 100 datasets is going to be repetitive, and can be done in a loop. but I'm stuck at getting `FROM bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod1956` in a while loop. I tried to string it, but to no avail. This is what I wrote and couldn't execute

```sql
DECLARE name STRING DEFAULT 'bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod';

SELECT stn,year,mo,temp,(SELECT CONCAT('`',name,'1955','`') AS name2)
FROM name2
```

The plan is once I can automate the names of the table I extract from, then I can put it in a while loop and extract all the necessary info in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop is not required to extract data from multiple tables. Instead you can [use wildcard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) as below:

```
SELECT
  stn, year, mo, ROUND(AVG(temp)) AS avg_temp
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '1955' AND '1957'
GROUP BY
  stn, year, mo
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip! This is very helpful. I didn't know such methods exist.